# I am getting shocked on an outlet whose power is isolated at the breaker!

Tags: electrical

I have added an extension to my home recently and wired everything onto the garage circuit with everything working properly as it should except for one outlet i keep getting a tingle from the ground wire while trying to put it in the wall. The weird part is there is no power supplied to this outlet. I have isolated the breaker. Through all of the remodel I have only used one circuit so no crossed from another breaker. everything is properly grounded. any inputs?

Comment: You say you added an extension - the extension is not on a subpanel ? The extension is on one additional breaker of what amperage. Your ground wire is touching something electrically hot - somewhere in its run. Is this at the end of the line or in the middle of the electrical run ? Do you have metal electrical boxes or plastic ?

Comment: Extension was a poor choice of words i enclosed part of a very large garage.

Comment: you don't get a tingle with out power. So something is hot what two things are you touching - the receptacle to be installed are your feet isolated with a rubber mat - just wondering about the receptacle wiring and also the floor grounding - Large Garage - separate slabs or the same slab ? Using the one hand rule - are you still getting a tingle ?

Comment: Is the neutral in your home in good shape? Because if not...

Comment: Is thes a new receptacle you are adding?  Or was it there before?

Comment: You're getting shocked by powe from a different breaker.  Try to find out which one.

Comment: I got it figured out today. I had a warranty repair on my water heater recently and the guy got a couple of wires mixed up causing a neutral cross.  After that no issues at all. Thanks guys!

Comment: You should consider having an electrician come inspect the work that was done both in the extension to the garage/home and the water heater. A Neutral being crossed should not present hot power on a ground wire.

Answer (score 3):

I got it figured out today. I had a warranty repair on my water heater recently and the guy got a couple of wires mixed up causing a neutral cross. After that no issues at all. Thanks guys! –

Answer (score 0):

**First of all** - Be very careful, when there's voltage on the ground wire you know some of the usual rules don't apply.

Couple ideas...
There is a load and line wire..   wires coming from the breaker should be a line and a ground (or neutral).  It might be possible that you have a switch or light somewhere wired backwards.  By that I mean you could have the line and load wrong.  It's possible that some other light fixture or switch has the line wire attached to the load and the load wire attached to the line..  This situation would cause all the fixtures to work correctly, except power could be going to switches and fixtures when they shouldn't be..

Second..  Could be a high impedance ground. What are you grounding yourself to, to feel the tickle? Maybe it's whatever ELSE your touching that has the problem.

Also circuit breakers don't open the neutrals. You might find neutrals from other circuits tied together.

Lastly..  Ground wires and line wires at circuit breaker are mixed up... I've seen something like this before - the subpanel feeding everything in  had ground wires and neutral wires mixed together on the same bus bar.